# Why does my code deadlock and how to fix it

Tags: go

Why does my code deadlock (followed by crash) on read from channel, I would expect it to block on read after the channel is read completely, but not crash. I understand it is a deadlock state as no one is writing to the channel and read blocks on it.

How can I change the code to read all the channel content and then exit from main instead of crash.

Go playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/rjXZZOx1FFZ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    news := make(chan int, 10)

    wg.Add(1)

    go foo(&wg, news) 

    wg.Wait()   

    for {
        fmt.Printf("reading: %v\n", <-news) 
        //crashes here after printing 0-9
    }

}

func foo(wg *sync.WaitGroup, news chan int) {
    for i:=0; i<10;i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Writing\n")
        news <- i
    }
    (*wg).Done()
}
```

Comment: Do not do `(*wg).Done()`! This creates a copy of the `sync.WaitGroup` struct value (which is marked `noCopy`!) and thus your `Done` call is applying to *a different wait group* than the one you passed in. Just `wg.Done()` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: As @ThunderCat shows you don't need a WaitGroup for synchronization the channel alone is adequate.  However, note that Done() is defined on a pointer type of sync.WaitGroup, so in your example you don't need `(*wg).Done()`, `wg.Done()` will suffice, and is preferred since you mustn't copy a `sync.WaitGroup`.  Haha, beat me too it @kbolino.

Comment: @kbolino: `(*wg).Done()` does not copy the sync.WaitGroup.   The expression `*wg` denotes the variable pointed to by `wg`.  The implicit address operation in the method call takes the address of this variable.

Comment: @ThunderCat Indeed, you are correct. Although Go doesn't make use of the lvalue or rvalue terminology, it seems that in the expression `(*wg).Done`, the `*wg` is functioning as an lvalue so no copy is made. I thought it was an rvalue and that the expression would be equivalent to `wg2 := *wg; wg2.Done()` which *would* involve a copy. So, there is nothing dangerous about `(*wg).Done()`! It is just unnecessary vs. `wg.Done()`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I learnt a few things today :) - Yes (*wg).Done() was working for me but I get the point of not doing *wg as its not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program deadlocks because main blocks on channel receive and there are no other goroutines that will send to that channel.

Use this approach to read all the channel content and then exit from main: main reads the channel until closed; foo writes all values and closes the channel.

```
func main() {
    news := make(chan int, 10)
    go foo(news)
    // range breaks when the channel is closed
    for v := range news { 

        fmt.Printf("reading: %v\n", v)
    }

}

func foo(news chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Writing\n")
        news <- i
    }
    // close channel to indicate that no more values will be sent.
    close(news) 
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kBPNJy5UO3K).

Comment: @ThunderCat, note that a best practice in Go is to ensure that channels are writable by as small a set of goroutines as possible. As implemented, it's possible for `main()` to inadvertently close or write to `news`--actions that could conflict w/ `foo()`.  By creating, writing to, and closing a chan in `foo` (and meanwhile, returning a read-only version of it) there's only one function you have to worry about re: channel gotchas, `foo()`.  Also, `foo()` could be easily re-architected to use other write strategies (like fan-out; fan-in) without worrying how other goroutines use the channel.

Comment: @ctt `foo` cannot return a value to `main` as you suggest in your comment.  I agree that it's useful to restrict the scope of sendable channels, but that's a distraction from the key points in this answer.

Comment: @ThunderCat, see the proposed edit.  With a few changes, you can land on the more idiomatic pattern for a function that generates data on a channel.  You're right that it would require `foo()`'s signature to change.  The benefit, though, is that the compiler will prevent `main()` from doing anything untorward with the channel.

Answer (score 2):

For an explanation of why this happens, the error message you get from the panic tells you the gist of it:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

You cannot have all of your goroutines waiting for other goroutines to do something. In this case, when the goroutine running `foo` is done, and the goroutine running `main` has received all of the messages (0 to 9) that were sent to the `news` channel, your program is left with one goroutine waiting to receive a message on a channel that will never have a message sent to it again because there are no other goroutines around to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The code crashes due to deadlock.

`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

You have a couple interesting problems with the original code.

If you close the news channel in your `foo` goroutine instead of deadlocking you instead will just run your infinite loop in `main` forever.

2 simple code changes should make this a bit more clear and will cause it to exit after processing the `news` items.

https://play.golang.org/p/qSU7sV7Wrov

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    news := make(chan int, 10)

    wg.Add(1)

    go foo(&wg, news)

    wg.Wait()

    for n := range news {
        fmt.Printf("reading: %v\n", n)
    }
    fmt.Println("We're out of news!")
}

func foo(wg *sync.WaitGroup, news chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Writing\n")
        news <- i
    }
    close(news)
    wg.Done()
}
```

Of course, you can rewrite it without using WaitGroups and just use the channels as others have pointed out and that may be a more elegant solution.

Comment: As noted above you should change `(*wg).Done()` to `wg.Done()`.

Comment: Since you're reading the channel to completion, you can skip the explicit check for `!ok` to see when the channel is closed and instead use a for-range loop on the channel.